# I get error ImportError: No module named _bootlocale while runnig pyinstaller on linux

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I get this error  `ImportError: No module named _bootlocale`,       when I tried to convert python script into exe on linux using pyinstaller
, I am using python version 3.10.5 and pyinstaller version 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by **installing newer version of pyinstaller** which is 5.4
using this command
`pip install pyinstaller==5.4` **then I accessed the newer version by its absolute path** which was `/home/kali/.local/bin/pyinstaller`
and I run the command `/home/kali/.local/bin/pyinstaller /home/kali/Desktop/main.py --onefile`
, so I convert python script to exe successfully